# I cannot delete an image in tmp folder when lamda function is triggered

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am generating an image using netwrokx library with the user's responses to my questions in the path /tmp/networkx.png in AWS lambda and mailing the user's this image.
[[networkx.png without any overlapping]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDRz5.png)

The problem I am facing here is after each session the image is not getting deleted in the tmp folder and in the next session the images overlaps. 
[[networkx.png with overlapping]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqw2m.png)

I have tried the following -

```
def delete_image():
    if os.path.exists("/tmp/networkx.png"):
       os.remove("/tmp/networkx.png")
       print("removed the image")
    else: 
       print("Image not removed")
```

Can anybody tell me how to delete the image in tmp folder once the image has been mailed to the user.

Comment: In your code are you actually creating a new image to draw on per session? Or are you using the old image object you've used before. If you do the latter make sure the image is cleared, or recreated before drawing onto the image. If you use the same image object without clearing it will overlap like you've shown.

Comment: Or maybe you are creating a new image, but then you have not cleared the list with nodes which should be drawn

Comment: Thank you so much. I was clearing the nodes of the graph instead of clearing the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across the same problem.

Please clear your image using :

```
    plt.clf()
```

Then save the image you created :

```
    plt.savefig("/tmp/networkx.png")<br>
```

And then close the image window:

```
    plt.close("/tmp/networkx.png")<br>
```